# Windows cannot detect secondary HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, drivers, pci

I disabled my LAN adapter for some reason a while back. When I re-enabled it my windows froze. I tried everything and finally removed the network driver from safe mode and reinstalled it again and it worked. I realized my secondary HDD was not detected anymore. The PCI simple communications driver was also missing and reinstalling the chipset driver did not solve this issue strangely.
I have solved the PCI driver issue using third party software but the secondary HDD is still not detected. With the secondary HDD connected it takes a long time for windows to boot up.

I can access the both HDDs through Ubuntu booted from a usb stick and I have run extensive tests on it through UBCD(Ultimate Boot CD) and no error shows up.

TLDR; The HDD shows up in BIOS and on any other OSes but nowhere on Windows. Not on the device manager, disk management etc.

EDIT: I am using H170M-PLUS motherboard and my OS is Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: “PCI Simple Communications” device is not a chipset item. It is usually a modem, or more recently it is the Intel Management Engine components.  Please [edit] your question and provide details about your computer make and model. A screenshot of the “missing” drive in Device Manager would also help.

Comment: Oh I see. Then it must be the Intel Management Engine as after installing that driver the missing driver is no longer shown. But as I stated that issued has been rectified and does not pertain to the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, in case anyone find this useful, after two fresh installation of Windows and oh so many driver reinstalls, I realized my problem was with the Intel Rapid Storage driver. Uninstalling and disabling the driver solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/ and evaluate the secondary driver health itself. I suspect there was something wrong with filesystem so Windows can't recognize it.